# flutter: How to set two btn in bottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-test

In this bottomNavigationBar I am using Column widget right now When I am using Row Then I am getting error How to make Like this ui btn in bottom.

[image]

This is my code.

```
  return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
          "Support",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: tSize16),
        ),
        leading: Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_rounded),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              tooltip: '',
            );
          },
        ),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: skyBlue,
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          _bodyChat(),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(green2Color),
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
                  side: BorderSide(color: green2Color, width: 0.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Text(
                "Yes! Resolved",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: tSize18, color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF)),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(skyBlue),
              shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0),
                  side: BorderSide(color: skyBlue, width: 0.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Text(
                "New Comment",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: tSize18, color: Color(0xFFFFFFFF)),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: what error did you get? I test your code, its ok with row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Row` instead of `Column`

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton(
```

Answer (score 0):

What I recommend you do is give the bottom navigation bar a `container` child so you can control the container's style independently and give that container a `Row` child which hosts your children button. Here's a code example and what it looks like:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              _val ?? "No button has been pressed",
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
        child: Container(
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.amber)),
                onPressed: (){
                  _switchButton("Left button has been pressed");
                },
                child: const Text("Left Button")),
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.teal)),
                onPressed: (){
                _switchButton("Right button has been pressed");
                }, 
                child: const Text("Right Button")),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image]